# ReportViewer control using ReportServerCredentials.NetworkCredentials

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, reporting-services, reportviewer

I'm using the ReportViewer control to access a SSRS 2008 Report from a VS2010 ASP.NET MVC 2 Web Application deployed on IIS7 with the following setup:

1. Forms Authentication and Anonymous Authentication enabled
2. ASP.NET Impersonation disabled
3. App pool identity configured to use local user account that has access rights to specific folders on the server required by the application
4. The webserver is not part of the domain but the SSRS server is on the domain

Since I need to use separate credentials to access SSRS Reports, I have implemented IReportServerCredentials as explained here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.ireportservercredentials(v=vs.100).aspx

The problem I'm having is it always goes to IReportServerCredentials.ImpersonationUser instead of IReportServerCredentials.NetworkCredentials where I need it to go because I'm retrieving the required credentials off web.config.

Maybe I'm missing something simple here but I've tried different combination of these settings and have had no luck. Any pointers on how I could get this working would be much appreciated!

My code:

```
[Serializable]
public sealed class MyReportServerCredentials : 
    IReportServerCredentials
{
    public WindowsIdentity ImpersonationUser
    {
        get
        {
            // Use the default Windows user.  Credentials will be
            // provided by the NetworkCredentials property.
            return null;
        }
    }

    public ICredentials NetworkCredentials
    {
        get
        {
            // Read the user information from the Web.config file.  
            // By reading the information on demand instead of 
            // storing it, the credentials will not be stored in 
            // session, reducing the vulnerable surface area to the
            // Web.config file, which can be secured with an ACL.

            // User name
            string userName = 
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings
                    ["MyReportViewerUser"];

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
                throw new Exception(
                    "Missing user name from web.config file");

            // Password
            string password = 
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings
                    ["MyReportViewerPassword"];

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
                throw new Exception(
                    "Missing password from web.config file");

            // Domain
            string domain = 
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings
                    ["MyReportViewerDomain"];

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(domain))
                throw new Exception(
                    "Missing domain from web.config file");

            return new NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain);
        }
    }

    public bool GetFormsCredentials(out Cookie authCookie, 
                out string userName, out string password, 
                out string authority)
    {
        authCookie = null;
        userName = null;
        password = null;
        authority = null;

        // Not using form credentials
        return false;
    }
}


this.MyReportView.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = new MyReportServerCredentials();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I implement this same class on every reporting page I need and it works correctly.

Check your web.config file.

I have:

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
</configuration>
</system.web>
```

Yes. Authentication mode "Windows".

However, I have worked also using Forms Authentication.

So I think this is more a permissions issue.

Check this post:

[UAC Windows 7 (Proffesional) 64 bit and SSRS 2008 R2 (10.50.1617) 64 bit](http://jhonatantirado.wordpress.com/2011/07/06/uac-windows-7-proffesional-64-bit-and-sql-2008-r2-10-50-1617-64-bit/)

Also this post:

[Reporting Services 2008: asking for username and password](http://jhonatantirado.wordpress.com/2011/04/16/reporting-services-2008-asking-for-username-and-password/)

Comment: Thanks Nathan for your response and useful links. It seems that when loading the report it calls ImpersonationUser first then NetworkCredentials next in the supplied ReportServerCredentials which I did not realize earlier. The articles in your links helped understand this better. It's working now as expected.